supervisor error log: sudo: a terminal is required to read the password
I am trying to use supervisord to daemonize a vapor server. This is my first time doing so. I am getting this one and only error in the supervisor error log:
sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S
option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper
sudo: a password is required

Another related post had the same error, and I applied the change they made to fix it but it didn't solve the problem for me.
PHP sudo: a terminal is required to read the password
Here's my supervisord.conf file:
[program:TextAlertServer]
command=swift run App serve
directory=/var/www/TextAlertServer
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stdout_logfile=/usr/local/var/log/supervisor/TextAlertServer-stdout.log
stderr_logfile=/usr/local/var/log/supervisor/TextAlertServer-stderr.log

I've tried adding in username and password for the server with no change.
Any ideas?

Running the server as root is a very bad idea and putting the files in /var/www is an invitation to trouble. I create a dedicated user called, imaginatively, vapor. This user has no shell, so can't actually log-in. I develop under my individual account, push changes then, as vapor (running su - vapor), pull the repo and build. My minimal supervisor conf file looks like:
[program:myserver]
command=/home/vapor/myserver/.build/release/Run serve --env production
directory=/home/vapor/myserver/
user=vapor
environment=PORT=8081,DBSTUFF=...

environment is a good way of extracting database credentials, so you don't put them in your source, and end-up exposing them on GitHub, etc. I always host my vapor apps behind nginx, hence the port value and always restrict access to localhost.

I could not get supervisor to work, so I turned to launchd. I was able to start my server using that. So far it's working brilliantly.
